# telebot. message.from_user.id как будто не существует

Tags: python, telebot

Пишу своего первого телеграмм бота
Мне нужно хранить датабазу сиквела, в которой ключом будет являться id пользователя
и проблема в том, что когда я хочу даже просто создать переменную, которая будет хранить этот айди, то этой переменной как будто нет, никаких ошибок ide или интерпретаор не выдают, просто игнорируют следующие строки:
id = int(message.from_user.id)
print(id)
Никакого принта нет, а код перестаёт дальше обрабатываться вовсе...
Я не понимаю, в чём причина, нигде в интернетах ничего не нашёл на эту тему

Comment: может так будет понятнее, я ещё новичок и могу криво излагать мысль
@bot.message_handler(content_types=['text'])
def main(message):
id = int(message.from_user.id)
print(id)

Answer (score 0):

print(message.from_user.id)
Либо
print("message.from_user.id")

Comment: Предложенные варианты не равнозначны: первый выведет идентификатор отправителя, второй -- напечатает строку `"message.from_user.id"`

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]